# Jersey server is disconnecting the client after 2 minutes

Tags: rest, jersey

Jersey REST API is disconcerting client after exact 2 mins however client is not configured for any kind of timeout.

To avoid the issue i am using Jersey Async API that helps me.

But my problem is why jersey is disconnecting the client. Does Jersey has 2 mins timeout configured in it, that i don't know and couldn't find that on Google.
I tried via cURL, postman etc, everywhere client is disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix of my problem.
The issue was due to DoS (Denial of Service) filter configuration. That was configured with 2 mins timeout. I changed that to extended value and so my REST API is working for long run processes.